# Encryption python file

Tags: python, security, encryption, pickle

i need to secure a file so I used this encryption using algoryth XOR

How i can modify this script to save the file "sortie" as an object (a string) in my fonction and not as a file on my desktop ?

```
from hashlib import sha256
entree = input("put file name : ")
sortie = input("put the final file: ")
key = input("put the key: ")
keys = sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()

with open(entree ,'rb') as f_entree:
    with open(sortie,'wb') as f_sortie:
        i=0
        while f_entree.peek():
            c = ord(f_entree.read(1))
            j = i % len(keys)
            b = bytes([c^keys[j]])
            f_sortie.write(b)       
            i=i+1
```

Comment: XOR isn't encryption, no matter how long the key is. Besides, your code is already "encrypting" the data in memory, in `b = bytes([c^keys[j]])`. You can use byte arrays as the input and output instead of files

Comment: so can you explain how i can do it using AES

Comment: You can use Fernet in the [cryptography module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/). It [uses AES-128 with SHA256 for hashing](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#implementation) in a way that prevents common mistakes. By default, a new encryption key is generated each time with `Fernet.generate_key()`, ensuring the key can't be easily generated using brute force.

Comment: To [generate a key from a password securely](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet) you need to salt it and hash it multiple times using a hashing algorithm specific for this. Modern computers are fast enough they can calculate millions of hashes per second so `sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()` is almost the same as no hashing at all.  The password needs to be salted and hashed *multiple* times to make calculating it on the fly as expensive as possible.

Comment: Another option is [pycroptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/examples) which works in a similar way.

Comment: i am sorry i didn t understand , how i can make encryption with AES

Comment: Did you read the links? There are a lot of duplicate questions in the past 10 years but many refer to old, unmaintained packages, so I posted links to the libraries mentioned in the recent answers. The Fernet examples use AES encryption in 3 lines. `key = Fernet.generate_key()`, `f = Fernet(key)`,`token = f.encrypt(b"A really secret message. Not for prying eyes.")`. The encrypted data (ciphertext) is `token`